# How can I estimate my population size when I've been given a range to work with?

Tags: estimation, population

I know this might seem like an obvious question to some, but I think my situation is a bit different and I'm a bit confused with the options i've found by google searches. I'm doing a research project in my school and I asked admin to give me the number of students that are currently at campus but for some reason they weren't allowed to tell me and gave me a range of 3000-4000 students. Should I just get the mean of this, 3500, and use that as my population mean?

Comment: Depends on the reason why you are interested in this figure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have no knowledge whatsoever if the number is closer to any of the boundaries of the interval, it is safe to assume that it can be any number in the interval. If it can be any number with equal probability, then it is safe to assume the midpoint as a best guess, since it is exactly in the middle of both boundaries and does not favor any option. By doing so, no matter what is the true value, you risk less by sticking to the midpoint, then to any other value, since at worst you can be wrong by 500 students. On the contrary, if you've chosen one of the boundaries as your best guess, at worst you could be wrong by 1000 students.

The above reasoning makes the naive assumption that any value in the interval is equally likely. However if you made some research and learned about sizes of other, similar schools, you could start with different assumptions and be more prone to make guesses closer to most likely value given your data.